# Limiting python file IO

Tags: python, security

So I would like users to be able to do some custom client side scripting for an game I am making but I don't want them to inadvertently download a malicious script. Is there any possible way to limit file IO in python without writing an evaluator to check each script? I guess what I am looking for is sandbox security.

Comment: This question is underspecified. What kind of custom scripting? Client side or server side? How are their scripts run? Why are you giving them access to files in the first place? Do they have access to anything else? etc. etc. Please edit your question with the 'edit' link.

Comment: How custom do you need the custom scripting to be? Maybe disallow import statements, give them access to only absolutely essential packages and then use regex to check for/disallow use of open()? This is naive and prone to exploitation no doubt, but that's why it's in a commment and not an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're looking for is some way to execute python in a sandbox, then you should refer to the following wiki.python.org links:

- [Sandboxed Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython)
- [How can I run an untrusted Python script safely?](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20can%20I%20run%20an%20untrusted%20Python%20script%20safely%20%28i.e.%20Sandbox%29)
- [Security](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Security)